# Multiple color pick jquery

Tags: jquery, colors

i have problem with jquery multiple colorpick. I use plugin Spectrum and i need update div color using jquery and colorpick. Here is code:

Create colorpicker from input #custom and #custom2

```
  $('#custom, #custom2').spectrum({
    showInput: true,
    color: "#f00",
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    move: function (color, color2) {setColor("#content", color, color2)},

    });
```

Here i have problem with "color2" because i dont know how i can get value from second colorpick to color2 variable. Varibale color is ok but i need select two different colors and set them to color and color2 variables.

if anyone know I would be grateful.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you try two seperate calls to the plugins instead of joining the selector.

Comment: yes if i use seperate script for #custom and #custom2 i get correct color values but i need use this one function with two color variables.If it is possible..